# How can i change key of array in laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel-9

After uploading a excel file ,I get values in  array given below

```
array:3 [▼ 
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "names" => "pa"
    "emails" => "pa@gmail.com"
    "passwords" => 123456
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "names" => "a123"
    "emails" => "a123@gmail.com"
    "passwords" => 123456
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "names" => "b123"
    "emails" => "b123@gmail.com"
    "passwords" => 123456
  ]
]
```

How can i change keys names as name, emails as email?

Comment: How did you get your array in the first place? Maybe change it there

Comment: I get it from excel. I cant excel. I have to change it  in controller

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? `foreach`ing over the array and changing the keys didn't work?

Comment: public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
dd($rows->toArray()); } . i have uploaded excel in laravel. Then i have to save in database. here i have to change keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the array_map function to transform the keys of each sub-array in your main array

Try this:

```
$originalArray = [
    [
        "names" => "pa",
        "emails" => "pa@gmail.com",
        "passwords" => 123456
    ],
    [
        "names" => "a123",
        "emails" => "a123@gmail.com",
        "passwords" => 123456
    ],
    [
        "names" => "b123",
        "emails" => "b123@gmail.com",
        "passwords" => 123456
    ]
];

$newArray = array_map(function ($item) {
    return [
        'name' => $item['names'],
        'email' => $item['emails'],
        'password' => $item['passwords']
    ];
}, $originalArray);

print_r($newArray);
```

that will return :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa
            [email] => pa@gmail.com
            [password] => 123456
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => a123
            [email] => a123@gmail.com
            [password] => 123456
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => b123
            [email] => b123@gmail.com
            [password] => 123456
        )

)
```